# Краткие методы объектов es6

Tags: ecmascript-6

В чём, на самом деле, заключается разница между именованной функцией и анонимной:

```
var obj = {
  a: function() { /* function body */ },
  b: function() { /* function body */ }
};
es5
Стало:

const obj = {
  a() { /* function body */ },
  b() { /* function body */ }
};
es6
```

Comment: Стало меньше писать. В чём собственно проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из того, что новый ES6 подход по сути является всего лишь "синтаксическим сахаром", поведение должно быть абсолютно одинаково. И так оно на самом деле и есть.

Дело в том, что разница между именованной и анонимной функцией заключается лишь в значении свойства `name` рассматриваемой функции. Так, например, в примере ниже первый `console.log` *должен* вывести `foo`, а второй - пустую строку.

```js
function foo() {
    // ...
}

let bar = function() {
    // ...
}

console.log(foo.name);
console.log(bar.name);
```

Мои слова также [подкрепляются](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-name) спецификацией 2015-го года (именно в ней появилось первоначальное определение этого свойства):

> Anonymous functions objects that do not have a contextual name associated with them by this specification do not have a name own property but inherit the name property of %FunctionPrototype%.

То есть у анонимной функции свойство `name` наследуется от `Function.prototype.name` и равно `""` (пустой строке).

Однако, если вы запустите этот пример, то можете увидеть (а можете и не увидеть), что *оба раза* имена функций *выводятся*: `"foo"` и `"bar"`. Не совсем то, что мы ожидали.

Что касается примера, приведенного Вами, то, как я говорил, оба варианта абсолютно идентичны, а значит и там и там перед нами анонимные функции, следовательно значения свойств `name` у обоих вариантов должно равняться пустой строке. Проверяем:

```js
var obj1 = {
  a: function() { /* function body */ },
  b: function() { /* function body */ }
};

const obj2 = {
  a() { /* function body */ },
  b() { /* function body */ }
};

console.log(obj1.a.name, obj1.b.name);
console.log(obj2.a.name, obj2.b.name);
```

Здесь видно 2 вещи:

1. Очевидно, что поведение действительно абсолютно одинаковое;
2. Очевидно, что результат не тот, что мы ожидали (по крайней мере в моей среде оба раза выводится `"a b"`).

### Промежуточный итог

Ответ на ваш вопрос

> В чём, на самом деле, заключается разница между именованной функцией и анонимной?

Ни в чем, поскольку оба варианта должны рассматриваться как анонимные функции.
Однако, по крайней мере у меня, поведение абсолютно противоположное. С чем это связано, сказать пока затрудняюсь, но, скорее всего, изменения в более современных версиях спецификации. Надо проверять.

И [пример (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) вдогонку:

```js
var f = function() {};
var object = {
  someMethod: function() {}
};

alert(f.name == ''); // true
alert(object.someMethod.name == ''); // также true
```

Оба раза должен выводить `true`, однако у меня оба раза выводит `false`.

### UPDATE

Собственно, ответ крылся в той же секции спецификации, но абзацем ранее:

> The value of the name property is an String that is descriptive of the function. The name has no semantic significance **but is typically a variable or property name that is used to refer to the function at its point of definition** in ECMAScript code. This property has the attributes { [[Writable]]: false, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: true }.

То есть значение свойства `name` приравнивается к названию переменной или свойства объекта, в которой хранится рассматриваемая функция (даже анонимная), и только если функция контекстно ни к чему не привязана, то `name` будет равен `""` (пустой строке):

```js
console.log((function() {}).name === "");
```

Comment: Скорее всего это браузерные оптимизации, добавлять имена функциям, мимо спецификации.

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev обновил ответ.